# Inner join one to many unique_id between two table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

one table t1 has one unique id u1

another table t2 has three unique_id u2a, u2b, u2c

How to make an inner join between two tables so that
u1 of table t1 join either u2a, u2b or u2c of table t2.

[image]

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Sounds like a database design error is now causing you some problems

Comment: Why not "ram usa" and "mohan usa" in the results? If you only need one name included, add the rules for including only one when multiple matches exist. Also, why is "chirs india" not included?

Comment: @DanGuzman  Thank you for your reply. apologize I changed output tables

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a best practice but try:

```
select t1.name,t2.country
      from table1 t1 
      inner join table2 t2
      on t1.u1=t2.u2a
union 
select t1.name,t2.country
     from table1 t1 
     inner join table2 t2
     on t1.u1=t2.u2b
union 
select t1.name,t2.country
       from table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2
       on t1.u1=t2.u2c;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/116

If you want the name in order you can add `order by name desc;` in the end of the query.

```
select t1.name,t2.country
      from table1 t1 
      inner join table2 t2
      on t1.u1=t2.u2a
union 
select t1.name,t2.country
     from table1 t1 
     inner join table2 t2
     on t1.u1=t2.u2b
union 
select t1.name,t2.country
       from table1 t1 
       inner join table2 t2
       on t1.u1=t2.u2c
order by name desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, Ergest for the quick solution.
Do we have any function in SQL which match either 1,2 or 3 in one line

Comment: for example" where u1 match either u2a, u2b,u2c". can we use contain or like function here

Comment: @kundankaushik, you are asking without using `union`?  I can't think of a better way for your problem.